# How to download data from a website daily to use in PowerBI

Tags: excel, automation, download, powerbi

I'm trying to automatically download data from this website https://usafacts.org/visualizations/coronavirus-covid-19-spread-map/ daily to be able to use it in PowerBI and have my dashboard update as new data is added.

I just don't know what the best way to go about this is, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to download the data each and every day, you just need to click
`Get data-> Other-> web` and provide the URL there, every time the data is update, you will get the latest values.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Power BI service you can create the report in Power BI Desktop, load it to the service and set up a dataset refresh, so the day will update for up to 8 times a day at times you can set. If you do not have the service (You can use the free version) you will have to update the data manually.

The MS Docs website goes through the set up [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/refresh-scheduled-refresh)

Answer (score 0):

Please use "Get Data -> Web" and provide the URL from where you want to fetch data. The will get downloaded into your dashboard.